# inherit constructor IS possible

Tags: inheritance, constructor

I find every on the internet that inheriting a constructor is not possible. But when I test it the derived class is also going trough the base class. See the code underneath. Can somebody explain me what I am seeing wrong?

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Derived D = new Derived();
            Console.Read();
        }      
    }

    public class Base
    {
        public Base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Base Destructor");
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside The Derived Constructor");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what you expect to happen. Constructing an object of a derived class always involves constructing the base portion of the object first.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. When  I run this code I see both lines: 'Inside base destrucor' (sorry,has to be 'constructor') and 'inside  derived constructor'.

Comment: That's what you should expect, in (almost) any OO language. If `Base` had some private variables which were set up in the `Base` constructor, how would you ever expect `Derived` to get them set up properly, without `Base`'s constructor running?

Comment: That's a good example. So why do I find in my study material this line?:  

Derived classes inherit all the members of the base class, except for constructors and destructors.

Comment: Because the base class' constructor is not explicitly usable. The compiler can (and will) call it; you can't.

Comment: Your study materials, though, are not well-written, at least on that point.